# Network security configuration not working with third party API

Tags: android, arcgis-runtime

My app is getting a SSLHandshakeException since I updated my app to use a network security config.

The app do requests to two servers. One of them is an develpment server accessible only in my company network. The other one is a public server running an ArcGIS Server. The domain is able to communicate over TLS 1.2.

So, I expect everything to works just adding a rule to my private development server. This is the content of my network security config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">172.17.1.14</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Unfortunately, any requests to my public server (using an third party API from server manufactury) are resulting in the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: Domain specific configurations require that hostname aware checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[], String, String) is used
        at android.security.net.config.RootTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(RootTrustManager.java:111)
        at com.esri.arcgisruntime.internal.e.a.a.checkServerTrusted(SourceFile:161)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.Platform.checkServerTrusted(Platform.java:212)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.verifyCertificateChain(ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.java:404)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeSsl.doHandshake(NativeSsl.java:375)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.startHandshake(ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.java:224)
```

Since my public server has a valid certificate and in TLS 1.2 aware, it would not happen, right?

The following network security config works fine, but it is insecure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
</network-security-config>
```

In addiction, I read that Facebook's Audience Network Android SDK also experienced issues with the network security configuration because they cache files at localhost. I've tried the same solution proposed by them but it also didn't work: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/android-network-security-config/

What did I have done wrong? Sniffing the emulator network did not show up any requests other then expected.

Comment: found any solution?

Comment: @NehaK I did not. I suspect that the ArcGIS platform is doing some redirects over HTTP, but could not find out for sure.

Comment: I was getting same issue, but then I tried to call the request using Glide so found the URL in error, and added that URL inside this <domain includeSubdomains> tag and it worked. May be will help somebody..

Comment: The URLs witch was the error root cause was a direct request or a redirect? Soon I'll have to look into this again, so if you post as an answer probably I can verify and accept.

Comment: no its fine.. if you will get any issue in future you can try this method..

Answer (score 3):

I've faced similar issues too. After some investigation, I've found an issue on Github where was a details description of why this issue could happen: https://github.com/microsoft/cpprestsdk/issues/1313
In short, it's a new behaviour of the Android Framework. If your network config contains any <domain-config blocks, Framework throws CertificateException if you call `checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType)` in `X509TrustManager`. So instead you should use `X509TrustManagerExtensions` and call method with a hostname in a signature.

Comment: hi @Plinio.Santos, did you solve your issue with this solution?

Comment: @ThinkTwiceCodeOnce I could not verify the answer since I'm not working on that project anymore