# Ktor socket client to self signed server: Domain specific configurations require ... checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[], String, String) is used

Tags: android, kotlin, ssl, ktor

I am trying to establish a Socket connection to a self signed server.

In my gradle file I'm using the following:

```
implementation 'io.ktor:ktor-network:1.6.5'
implementation 'io.ktor:ktor-network-tls:1.6.5'
```

My code to establish the connection:

```
socketConnection = aSocket( ActorSelectorManager( Dispatchers.IO ))
    .tcp( ).connect( InetSocketAddress( "192.168.1.5", 8080 ))
    .tls( Dispatchers.IO )
```

Now I tired to trust the cert by adding

```
android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
```

to my `AndroidManifest.xml` in the application tag.

My `network_security_config.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">192.168.78.74</domain>
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="@raw/my_cert"/>
        </trust-anchors>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

when I run the application I get this error:

```
java.security.cert.CertificateException: Domain specific configurations require that hostname aware checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[], String, String) is used
    at android.security.net.config.RootTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(RootTrustManager.java:112)
    at io.ktor.network.tls.TLSClientHandshake.handleCertificatesAndKeys(TLSClientHandshake.kt:234)
    at io.ktor.network.tls.TLSClientHandshake.negotiate(TLSClientHandshake.kt:165)
    at io.ktor.network.tls.TLSClientHandshake$negotiate$1.invokeSuspend(Unknown Source:14)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:571)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:750)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:678)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:665)
```

Comment: This is a known bug (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTOR-2243). I've added a comment about your use case. This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/64501580/13963150 describes well the underlying problem.

Comment: Hi, did you find any solution to this?

Comment: I'm using javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket for now

Answer (score 3):

I am using ktor and wanted to monitor the traffic using proxy man

In order to solve the exception I had to add the proxy directly to the HttpClient and add a custom trustmanager that does not check the certificate

Only use this for development purposes..

```
val client = HttpClient(CIO) {
    engine {
        proxy = ProxyBuilder.http("http://PROXY_IP_HERE:PROXY_PORT_HERE/")
        https {
            trustManager = MyTrustManager(this)
        }
    }
}

class MyTrustManager(private val config: TLSConfigBuilder) : X509TrustManager {
    private val delegate = config.build().trustManager
    private val extensions = X509TrustManagerExtensions(delegate)

    override fun checkClientTrusted(certificates: Array<out X509Certificate>?, authType: String?) {}

    override fun checkServerTrusted(certificates: Array<out X509Certificate>?, authType: String?) {}

    override fun getAcceptedIssuers(): Array<X509Certificate> = delegate.acceptedIssuers
}
```

With the following network security config:

```
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config>
        <!-- Make sure your URL Server here -->
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">your_domain</domain>
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="user"/>
            <certificates src="system"/>
        </trust-anchors>
    </domain-config>

    <debug-overrides>
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="user" />
            <certificates src="system" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </debug-overrides>

    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
</network-security-config>
```